# Is it possible to nest collection/table views in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a list of items (blue), and within each item there is a collection of sub items (yellow). Will it be possible to replicate this layout in iOS with collection and table views?

I was going to create the blue items as a table view with custom cells. Then within this custom cell (blue), I was going to place a collection view (yellow items).

1. Is this possible?
2. Is my choice of table view for the blue items and collection view for the yellow items correct?

**See diagrams**
[image]

More specifically, the layout will be like the following, varying content in each blue item and they are expandable, the yellow items becoming visible when the item has been expanded.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UICollectionViews will work for both yellow and blue. In fact, collectionviews use "sections" and "cells" to organize your data visually. A section would be one of your "item groups" and a cell would be a "yellow square."  The layout you have shown should be very simple to implement using UICollectionViewFLowLayoutDelegate methods. Just follow the Apple docs...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH2-SW1

Comment: Nick I have added more detail to my question. The layout I am after is explained better in my new diagram. Do you think your suggestion is still applicable?

Comment: Yup.  The way I'd do it would be to implement a UICollectionView with subclassing of the UICollectionViewCell.  If you want to have a special touch point like that arrow you have to use the detailDisclosureView and subclass it and implement the delegate touchandling methods.  The didSelect method can be used to load a new UICollectionView into the cell from whatever data model you're using.  Either way you can do it all via delegates and subclassing the UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a collection view subclass that can help you achieve that layout: https://github.com/nazeehshoura/NExpandableCollectionView

Use `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` to represent your blue items, and `UICollectionViewCell` to represent your yellow items. NExpandableCollectionView will expand and show the yellow items when a corresponding blue item is clicked.